# How to develop custom fields for SharePoint Online list - Lookup with Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

We have a SharePoint 2010 list where a custom field "Lookup with Picker" has been implemented through a farm solution. We need to migrate the list to SharePoint Online but since we cannot deploy farm solutions in O365 environment, is there a alternative or workaround to implement that custom field in SP Online?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSLink](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) to change field render for classic view in SharePoint online.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/custom-field-type-sharepoint-add-in

For modern view, you need create [SPFx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions) solution.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_MSFT for your response. I am looking to develop something similar to the one shown in this [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=lookupwithpicker)

Comment: The custom field type can be applied to on-premise server only, SharePoint online doesn't allow server side object coding.

Comment: I understand that but is there any workaround/alternative to develop something similar for SP Online?......Is there anything available readymade in SharePoint App Store?